# Angular signals and ngrx store unit testing

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs

I've recently migrated to angular 16 and I wanted to migrate from observables to signals API. I faced an issue in my unit tests migration, and I don't know why and how to fix this issue.
I've simply prepared a basic project which shows the issue. you can check the specs files here: https://github.com/BlueWorld1/angular-signals/blob/main/src/app/app.component.spec.ts

You can clone the repos, install deps and run it locally/debug.

The issue is: when I use overrideSelector provided by the MockStore class in @ngrx/store/testing (coupled to provideMockStore() as a provider), it does not works as expected.

- When we put the instruction overrideSelector in beforeEach, the test pass.
- When we put the instruction overrideSelector in it, the test fails, even the mockedStore contain the right value.
- If you comment this line:https://github.com/BlueWorld1/angular-signals/blob/main/src/app/app.component.spec.ts#L30 then all tests will pass.

How could I make my unit test working using overrideSelector in it ? (or equivalent behaviour)

Thanks in advance.